# Accessibility: Embedding a UITableView inside the Footer of a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I am trying to reuse an existing UITableViewController by embedding a UITableView in the footer of an existing table.

The premise is that on selection of a row, the footer will appear with a list of further, related options. This works fine but the accessibility inspector is unable to read the rows in the table embedded in the footer.

I created a quick sample of code to show the issue.

Code for the main UITableViewController

```
@interface MyUITableViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyUITableViewController{
    MySubUITableViewController *dataSourceClass;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    dataSourceClass = [[MySubUITableViewController alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(section == 0){
        CGRect tableFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 200);

        UITableView *view = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];

        view.rowHeight = 30;
        view.scrollEnabled = YES;
        view.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
        view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        view.bounces = YES;

        view.delegate = dataSourceClass;
        view.dataSource = dataSourceClass;
        return view;
    }
    return nil;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(section == 0)
        return 200;
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"identifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %d Row %d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

The code for the table to embed within the footer

```
@implementation MySubUITableViewController {

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"subCell";
  UITableViewCell *cell;

  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }

  cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Footer Row %d", indexPath.row];
  return cell;
}
@end
```

Anyone know how to get round the Footer rows not being read by accessibility?

I tried

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, nil);
}
```

but to avail.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the only solution I could get to work, is to create a custom UITableViewCell which implements the UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate delegates.

Effectively creating a table inside a UITableViewCell.

Something along the lines of:

```
@interface MyTableWrappingCell()  <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, weak) UITableView *myTableView;
@end

@implementation MyTableWrappingCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        UITableView *myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        myTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        myTableView.dataSource = self;
        myTableView.delegate = self;
        [self.contentView addSubview:myTableView];
        self.myTableView = myTableView;
    }
    return self;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"subCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"internal Row %d", indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void) forceLoad{
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

Accessibility is then able to read the contents.